# What does the muezzin call from a minaret outside of prayer time?

Tags: masjid, adhan, taraweeh, islamic-countries

I am currently in Indonesia/Java and the muezzin/minaret/mosque calls go on for much longer than what I've experienced before. I've been to a couple of Muslim countries and they've done the calls 5 times a day, couple of minutes and that's that.

But here it's 21:03, I have checked the prayer times and the last one was more than two hours ago. The call is still going on. It's currently Ramadan, can it be due to that? And what is the content of the call?

Comment: I was going to suggest that it relates to the post sunset meal time during Ramadan, but the sunset time in Jakarta is about 6pm.   I also checked [this](https://www.edarabia.com/prayer-times-indonesia/) site and it says that Isha should be at 8pm.

Comment: Are you sure its Azaan? Maybe they are performing Taraweeh on the loudspeaker, or maybe its some other Dhikr.

Comment: No no, I'm not sure it's Azaan. I'm not a Muslim myself and I don't speak the local language (this question was originally in the Travel StackExchange site). It may well be something different but I am wondering what it may be. It's just that this is my first time hearing them go "overtime" and use the loudspeakers for something more than the Azaan. I looked up Taraweeh, it sounds plausible. I didn't know how to phrase the Google query because I don't know the Muslim terminology, so this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't be certain unless you record a chunk of it so that we can hear it. But given the time (after the last prayers i.e. Isha) it is likely to be Taraweeh. Taraweeh is a prayer that is offered in Ramadan, after Isha. Muslims try to complete reciting the whole Quran within the month (or typically within 27 days), so it can last for around 1.5-2 hours per day.